# @font-face not working after installing ParcelJS

Tags: html, css, sass, font-face, parceljs

I previously setup Gulp to use Sass, Pug and Babel. The fonts loaded fine. I switched to using [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) now and it's working as expected, except one thing. The fonts arent loading in.

Here is the entirety of `_fonts.sass`:

```
@font-face
  font-family: "MyWebFont"
  src: url(../fonts/economica-regular-otf.eot)
  src: url(../fonts/economica-regular-otf.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
  url(../fonts/economica-regular-otf.woff2) format("woff2"),
  url(../fonts/economica-regular-otf.woff) format("woff"),
  url(../fonts/economica-regular-otf.ttf) format("ttf")

@font-face
  font-family: "MyWebFontBold"
  src: url(../fonts/economica-bold-otf.eot)
  src: url(../fonts/economica-bold-otf.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
  url(../fonts/economica-bold-otf.woff2) format("woff2"),
  url(../fonts/economica-bold-otf.woff) format("woff"),
  url(../fonts/economica-bold-otf.ttf) format("ttf")

body
  font-family: 'MyWebFont', 'Titillium Web', sans-serif
  text-rendering: auto
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision
```

Folder strcuture is as follows:

```
/dist
/src
-- / pug
--- index.pug
-- / sass
--- _fonts.sass
--- _animations.sass
--- _blocks.sass
--- _elements.sass
--- styles.sass
-- / js
--- // all the scripts
-- / fonts
--- // all the fonts are here
```

You can find the project files here ('new' branch): [GitHub](https://github.com/IbrahimButt/Vanilla-JavaScript-Calculator/tree/new)

Comment: wonder if you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: In `package.json` I edited the `build` script to be `"build": "parcel build src/pug/index.pug --public-url ./ -d dist"`.

Then I edited `_fonts.sass` so `@font-face` doesn't go up a directory. For example, `src: url(../fonts/economica-regular-otf.eot)` became `src: url(./fonts/economica-regular-otf.eot)`.

There was good reason for this, but it has been a while and I don't remember now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this a while back.

In `package.json` I edited the `build` script to be `"build": "parcel build src/pug/index.pug --public-url ./ -d dist"`.

Then I edited `_fonts.sass` so `@font-face` doesn't go up a directory. For example, `src: url(../fonts/economica-regular-otf.eot)` became `src: url(./fonts/economica-regular-otf.eot)`.

It has been a while now since I figured this out so I don't remember the reasoning behind this, but it worked.